# How to tokenize decimal numbers separated by . (dot)

Tags: python, nltk

I am using NLTK to tokenize a text file, and in this type of file I have age information which is usually in the format of a decimal number separated by dot (like 36.11 for example).

Now, when I tokenize the text I get something like this:

`[ '36', '.', '11']`

I want to know how to make the numbers, like for instance 36.11, to be treated as a single token.

Edit: I'm using PlaintextCorpusReader to read multiple text files, and separating with corpus.words() and joining them together. So I can't use word_tokenize (or least don't know how to).

```py
corpus_root = '/home/user/Documents/CC/November/01-11-2018/Texts'
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
palavras = corpus.words()
wordlist = ["".join(word) for word in palavras]
```

Comment: `from nltk import word_tokenize; word_tokenize('This is the 36.11 number')`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which tokenizer, you're using in `nltk`.

If you're using the de factor `word_tokenize`, this shouldn't happen:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize('36.11')
['36.11']
>>> word_tokenize('This is the 36.11 number')
['This', 'is', 'the', '36.11', 'number']
```

Comment: The problem is I'm loading a bunch of .txt files as a corpus (with PlaintextCorpusReader) and using corpus.words() to tokenize. If I try to use word_tokenize I get an error. I'll edit my code in the main question.

Comment: Could you upload your text somewhere? It's not possible to debug without seeing what's wrong with the code and the data =)